# What is the best way to manage the DataCacheFactory object in a web application?

Tags: asp.net, appfabric, appfabric-cache, datacachefactory

It says it is the best practice to instantiate one single instance of `DataCacheFactory` object per execution thread. I am implementing AppFabric caching in a web asp.net application.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

```
public class AppFabricCacheWrapper
{
    public static DataCache GetCache(string cacheName)
    {
        var cacheFactory = GetDataCacheFactory();
        return cacheFactory.GetCache(cacheName);
    }

    private static DataCacheFactory GetDataCacheFactory()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["DataCacheFactory"] == null)
        {
            CreateFactoryInstance();
        }

        return (DataCacheFactory)HttpContext.Current.Items["DataCacheFactory"];
    }

    private static void CreateFactoryInstance()
    {
        var config = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration
        {
            Servers = GetServerNames(),
        };

        HttpContext.Current.Items["DataCacheFactory"] = new DataCacheFactory(config);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<DataCacheServerEndpoint> GetServerNames()
    {
        var namesList = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>
            {
                new DataCacheServerEndpoint("SERVER1", 22233),
                new DataCacheServerEndpoint("SERVER2", 22233)
            };

        return namesList;
    }
}
```